# VB.NET Does SqlConnection get closed automatically in a Try/Catch if exception is thrown?

Tags: vb.net, sqlconnection

Didn't find this exact question/answer. In VB.NET, If I open a SqlConnection in a Try/Catch block, and an Exception is thrown (caught properly), is the connection implicitly closed, or do I have to close it? (does it even get opened if the Try failed?)

Would "test" this myself, but I don't really know how to tell if the connection is open or closed when the Exception is thrown.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not closed if it's open... Put a breakpoint where you create the connection, make a nullable statement and use it. You should then have an exception and from there hover over your connection instance and look for the state. It will be open if you opened it or closed... You can add a finally block to close it if it's open. `VB.NET Does SqlConnection get closed automatically in a Try/Catch if exception is thrown?` ***no***...

Comment: Thanks Codexer. If I add conn.close() (or .Dispose()) in a Finally block and the connection is NOT open at the time, is a different error thrown or is it graceful?

Comment: No only if your object is nothing... So the answer is no it wont...

Comment: SqlConnection is a managed object so soon after it goes of out of scope, GC marks it for collection. So yes, connection will be closed at some later time when GC will collect it. But... It's best practice to manually close it to make it available for reopen by some other request. I mean physical connection.

Comment: @Saleem `SqlConnection is a managed object`, I would ***disagree***. It is a un-managed object. The `SqlConnection` is not under direct control of the GC, when you open a connection it will use resources on the server and possibly other **non-net** resources. Also if making to many connections and not closing/disposing of them correct, the GC is brainwashed at what to do with them at that point. The `SqlConnection` implements `IDisposable`, so dispose of them :)

Comment: `If it implements IDisposable, isn't GC going to call it at collection time?` it ***should***, but can't guarantee that the finalizers are going to happen either. The real problem is holding on to those resources, they need to be released when done...

Comment: Yes, you are right @Codexer. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx. It clearly says connection will not get closed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Thanks, I've read, re-read, read again and re-read about all the connections stuff I want for awhile :) thank's for the post! @Saleem

Comment: @Codexer You can count on a .NET connection to correctly call its finalizer when collected - - that's not the issue. As you point out, the issue is that we don't know if/when that will occur because memory in .NET is non-deterministic. Even if an object is out of scope, it may/will stay on the heap for some time.

Comment: @Codexer You say, "The SqlConnection implements IDisposable, so dispose of them". That implies that we should call Dispose on any object that implements IDisposable. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: `The SqlConnection implements IDisposable, so dispose of them` that was what I said. Clearly talking about `SqlConnections`...

Comment: So, what if I said "The Textbox implements IDisposable, so dispose of them". How would that be any different?  Your statement (intentional or not) clearly "implies" that if IDisposable is implemented, you should call Dispose. Now, doing this won't actually harm your code, but as you correctly pointed out when you clarified yourself, it depends on the object.

Comment: **ALL SQLCONNECTIONS SHOULD BE DISPOSED** how's that? It varies from object to object and what is being passed off. You mentioned **any object**... I didn't...

Comment: Gentlemen! We're all coders here! Appreciate the discussion - let's all have a beer now. :)

Comment: @ScottMarcus my point was you said he needs to declare the variable before, fine, but wrong as it should be wrapped... :) Also if it was wrapped in a using statement he would not have to worry about using a finally statement correct?

Comment: "It should be wrapped."  Why? Who says so? In a Try/Catch you MUST declare the variable outside if you intend to access it in the Finally. The question was about TRY/CATCH! What part of that don't you get? Do you know what a Using compiles down to? A Try/FInally!

Comment: So the **object** is disposed properly. Then he wouldn't need a finally block... I agree with the Try/Catch didn't say I didn't. My point is if he was using the `Using` statement, he wouldn't need to worry if it's been disposed/closed...

Comment: So what? THAT WASN'T THE QUESTION!

Comment: Stack Overflow has fairly straight-forward protocols and guidelines for questions and answers and if you really don't get that berating (and that is what you have been doing) someone for not providing a solution to a question that wasn't asked is inappropriate, then maybe Stack Overflow isn't the place for you.

Comment: @ScottMarcus good discussion, I enjoyed it. Good luck in your en devours!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.** That's why you'll want to declare the connection variable before the try/catch and add a finally to it to ensure you have a place where the connection can be closed and disposed:

```
 Dim con As New SqlClientConnection( . . .)

 Try
      ' DB Operations (create, read, update, delete) here
      con.open()

 Catch SqlClientException (ex)

     ' Deal with exception
 Finally
      ' Code here will always run, whether or not the try code succeeded
      ' or if you wound up in a catch block. You can safely call .close()
      ' or (as shown below) .dispose() because if the connection is already
      ' closed/disposed, the call doesn't do anything.


      ' Dispose is what you want - it will not only close the
      ' connection, but it will release the .NET reference to
      ' the remote resource, freeing up that resource (the database
      ' in this case) to serve other clients.

      con.Dispose()

 End Try
```

Comment: @Scott Marcus `This is the correct answer`, I beg to differ. If a ***non SqlException*** is thrown from code, this will still throw another un-handled exception :)

Comment: You'll notice that my answer contained pseudo-code. The OP wasn't asking what the correct ways to catch exceptions was. I limited the code to the relevant information.

Comment: Agreed, `Would "test" this myself, but I don't really know how to tell if the connection is open or closed ` what about offering how to test?

Comment: That wasn't the question and the answer doesn't need testing. It's correct. Should I offer instructions on how to test if an object is instantiated or not as well? That wasn't the question.